# OOP Structure for a PHP/Twitter/Facebook App

Tags: php, oop

I'm making a simple PHP application with Twitter/Facebook integration to practice OOP concepts and patterns, and I need help with how it should be designed.

#### What my app will do

Basically, once the user logs in, he's show a form with **title and body** field. When he clicks on "Post", this content will be appropriately transformed and posted to Facebook and Twitter. Of course, he'll also get an option to authenticate my FB/Twitter app if he hasn't already done so. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

#### The structure I've come up with till now

Since **database access** will have to be shared amongst multiple files, I'm using a Singleton pattern. Essentially, I have a DB class with a static *mysqli link* and a static method to get this database link. The models will use mysqli functions with this single link. (I don't want to abstract the database type just yet.)

I have a **User** class which holds a user's data, like it's *id, username and hashed password*. It has methods to retrieve user based on id, credentials and even save the current user to the db.

An **Auth** class manages session and returns a **User** object for a valid user. So, it manages logging in, and keeping the user logged in between page visits.

#### The structure I'm having problem with

I now need access to the **Twitter and Facebook** information of the user. Of course, they'll be in separate tables, and have separate classes to interact with them. But each of this class is associated with a **User**.

So, when I'm fetching user information from the database, I'll also use JOINs to fetch corresponding data from the Twitter and Facebook table. Then, my plan is to have a Twitter and Facebook object instantiated within my User object. So, these two classes can be accessed as say $user->twitter->post("Something");.

Is this a good structure, or is there a better way to organize classes? This is a simple app, and coding is not my concern. My concern is the structure, since I should be able to add new social networks to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferable to keep persistence functions out of domain objects. Instead of having the `User` class load and save itself, I would have a `UserRepository` interface, for example:

```
interface UserRepository {
  public function findUser($username);
  public function save(User $user);
}
```

and a `MysqlUserRepository` class that implements this interface. That way you keep database-specific code out of the `User` class.

Similarly, I would pull social networking functions into their own interface, say:

```
interface SocialNetworkService {
  public function post($status);
}
```

and separate implementations for `FacebookService` and `TwitterService`. This allows you to add support for new social networks without having to modify the `User` class.

These services can then simply wrap around a user object and provide their services for that user:

```
$fb = new FacebookService($user);
$fb->post("blah");
```

A common principle behind all of these decisions is the single responsibility principle: your `User` class should have only one reason to change, and that is when you need to change the model of a user. Any other changes, such as dealing with databases or social networks, shouldn't affect the `User` class.

Comment: I can see the structure of my app more clearly now. Thanks for the help!